# React-Native componentwillunmont - proper use

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native new version ( v: 0.62.2 ).

I take action on the page I created and go to another page with react-navigation

```
function Register({ route, navigation }) {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const _go = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Home', { });
  }

  const _firebase = () => {
    firebase.messaging().getToken(firebase.app().options.messagingSenderId).then(x => _token(x)).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     _firebase();

    return () => { 
      _go, _firebase
    };
  }, [navigation, loading, name]);
}
```

I call the _go function after doing the above code
What I want to ask is, is the page open when I go to another page with the _go function?

The following code is enough to close the page to improve performance

```
return () => { 
      _go, _firebase
    };
  }, [navigation, loading, name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

componentWillUnmount is used when you are going to remove event listeners, timers and etc.
But you didn't declare such things in your code.
Anyway if you are going to implement cWU effect then you need to define it on componentDidMount like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () {
        // remove events and timers
    }
}, []);
```

If you pass emptry array as second parameter it is same as componentDidMount. 
Hope this helps you to understand.
In addition please refer to this article about lifeCycles - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html